# SSH session through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

I am having issues with making an ssh session through PHP. I have looked high and low and cannot figure out how to do this.  I see on one of your posts you state that you are able to make this connection, I would greatly appreciate the help.  I have included a file called 'class.shell2.php' which has the basic functions I need which are to connect to the ssh server and send commands to the terminal.  However when I try to connect to the server it give me an error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /****/*****/****/class.shell2.php on line 62" Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SSH2 functions ([including `ssh2_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php)) are not part of the base php distribution.  They're available through PECL.

[Check the "Installing/Configuring" page for SSH2 on the PHP documentation site](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) for info about how to install this module.

Comment: I've looked at that doc and cannot figure out how it works.  I am on a mac and the instructions I believe are for darwin or linux?  I believe I have everything installed but it is still not working for me.  Is there any guides on how to make this work on mac?

Comment: Mac OS-X *is* "Darwin". They are the same. If you have instructions for Darwin, then follow those.  If it still doesn't work, then you'll need to edit your answer, and tell us exactly what you have tried; and what results (and errors) you have gotten.  Alternately, you might consider using [`proc_open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) or [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to call ssh as a command-line application.  If your needs are fairly simple, this can work well, but you'll need to setup ssh client certificates for authentication.

Comment: I apologize it is not darwin its debian I believe I'm not sure.  however I have found another package called phpseclib which has a net_ssh2 class that is used for making ssh connections from php however I am not able to connect i get a failed login message everytime.  I have setup and the example states but cannot login. the manual is online.  All I need to do is make an ssh connection to another computer and execute a serial command from the terminal.  Could I do this with proc-open() or shell_exec(). I tried the shell_exec, but how would i enter username and password for shh session.

Comment: Yes: `shell_exec('ssh username@hostname.com \'some command\'')`. You'll need to use SSH client certificates instead of password for authentication -- this will allow your script to login securely without providing a password. [Here's how to setup a client certificate](http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html).  I suggest that you include the `-i` option to ssh to ensure that ssh picks up your identity file correctly when run from PHP.